# Python BeautifulSoup scraping tables from a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a webpage that has a table of users that are currently signed into the site

I'm using the below code to sign into the site

```
browser = RoboBrowser()
loginURL = 'https://geico.aisreview.com/ais/admin.aspx'
browser.open(loginURL)
form = browser.get_form(id='form1')
form['txtPWD'].value = 'myPassword'
browser.submit_form(form)
```

And I'm using this code to try and pull the data from the table. Right now I'm just trying to print it for testing purposes

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(loginURL)
table = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "rgMasterTable"})
for myTable in table:
  table_body = myTable.find('tbody')
  try:
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    for tr in rows:
      cols = tr.find_all('td')
      for td in cols:
        print td.text
  except:
    print "no tbody found"
```

When running the code I don't get any errors, but nothing prints out. I was able to determine that the for loop is never being entered but I can't figure out why.

Comment: I would wager that your `table` list is empty.

Comment: Can you print `table`?

Comment: Which for loop?
Also print the variables you are iterating in... like `print(table)` `print(rows)``print(cols)`

Comment: @rahlf23 I printed out table and it is empty, but on the site there are 6 rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) to read tables from html

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

loginURL='http://example.com'
res=requests.get(loginURL)

tables=pd.read_html(res.text) # return list of tables
print(tables)#will display all the tables, please slice the list for your required table.
```

or you can directly give the url like `pd.read_html(loginURL)`